# Solr: is query numfound >0, use query, else use another query?

Tags: solr

Is there anyway to put this into one solr query?  Execute one query, if numfound >0, return the results for that query.  Otherwise execute a different query and return those results.

I've been doing something vaguely similar to this by giving a higher weight to the first query:
q=firstQuery^5 || secondQuery

But would rather prefer the logic detailed in my question.  Anyway to do this?

Thanks!